# twitter get users by country

Tags: twitter

The general question I'm solving is:

1. to get a list of users with specified country.
2. to get a list of hashtags in tweets with specified country

I checked api man, but I don't see any method for this.
Could you please help me with these questions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If there's nothing in the API then you won't be able to do it.

Comment: but there are a lot of sites with this info. like top 100 users in UK

Comment: if sites are doing it it's got to be in the API hopefully someone will respond, I looked and didn't see an obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct means to accomplish this with the API. You need to derive such data by monitoring the sources of data you do have access to, such as the sample stream offered in the Streaming API.